# using $cut to see only the month

Tags: command-line, cut

This is what I get by doing $date:

```
Wed Feb  1 16:21:58 PST 2017
```

I want to use cut command and pipe to print only 'Wed'.

```
date | cut -f '1-3'
```

How come the command above does not do anything? How should I fix it?

Comment: If you are trying to cut the first 3 *characters*, you need `-c` not `-f`. Does your `date` command allow you to specify the format directly e.g. `date +%a`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temporary hidden file to load the month into a variable, and it will remain there until the session ends or the variable has something else loaded into it. Here is an example script that can be run from any directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
month=$(date | cut -c 5-7)
echo $month
```

will return `Feb`. You now have a variable containing the month with which you can do whatever you like. Don't forget to include the `-c` argument in the future so that cut knows to be pulling characters from columns, rather than bytes from a string.

Comment: If latency if a concern, you can eliminate file I/O and consolidate some of those steps with `month=$(date | cut -c 5-7)`.

Answer (score 1):

The date utility has it's own format paramter utilising the standard format codes

You'll want

```
#date +"%a"
```

which will give `Thu`

or

```
date +"%A"
```

which will give `Thursday`

ref: http://ss64.com/bash/date.html

**Re: why isn't "cut" working.**

The -f option is based upon TAB delimited spacing, so the -d option is required to specify a space as the delimiter as per @rakesh-n's response.

```
date | cut -d' ' -f1
```

ref: http://ss64.com/bash/cut.html

Comment: `date` is not a bash command. It's a system command. It's also defined by posix: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
date | cut -d' ' -f1
```